# Laravel Eloquent Query Issue with checking data through relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a problem with retrieving the data from Users table:

```
User:
-id int
-name string
-compartment_id int
```

This is related with `compartments` table:

```
Compartment:
-id int
-name string
-country_id int
```

Which is related to `countries` table:

```
Country:
-id int
-name string
```

User model:

```
public function compartment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Compartment::class, 'compartment_id');
}
```

Compartment model:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Country model:

```
public function compartments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Compartment::class);
}
```

I am using Livewire PowerGrid to display data in data tables.

I wanted to get All Users with `compartment_id` = `null` and All Users that `compartment->country_id` is equal to `Auth::user()->compartment->country_id`.

I'm stuck with:

```
User::whereIn('compartment_id', Compartment::select('country_id')
->where('country_id', Auth::user()->compartment->country_id))->where('compartment_id', null);
```

It must be the builder, without `->get()` because it's interpreted by PowerGrid correctly.
Can someone instruct?

Comment: You have 2 queries for compartment_id that conflict each other, because a single compartment_id can't be both null and in a list of values. Do you want `compartment_id IS NULL OR compartment_id IN (list)`?

Comment: `compartment_id` in Users table is `nullable()` until it's assigned to it. It must be `AND` because I want all users without compartment assigned and those which compartment country matches with compartment country of logged User(Admin in that case) all in one query...

Comment: @kalview, So it is OR condition

Comment: @YasinPatel sorry, my mistake... Yesterday I was too exhausted and this "misthinking" caused following problem. Thanks for response!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query,

You will get all users without compartment assigned and those whose compartment country matches with compartment

```
User::whereHas('compartment',function($q){
  $q->where('country_id', Auth::user()->compartment->country_id);
})
->orWhereNull('compartment_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

```
User::whereIn('compartment_id', Compartment::select('compartment_id')
     ->where('country_id', Auth::user()->compartment->country_id))
     ->where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
     ->orWhereNull('compartment_id');
```

I thought wrongly (by mistake) that it should be `AND` clause, not `OR`.
Thanks all for help.